# Reverse ajax Comet/Polling implementation for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am looking for ASP.Net MVC implementation for reverse ajax comet/polling. Can anyone provide some good link or tutorial

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to check [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) library.

PokeIn gives you an enhanced JSON functionality to makes your server side objects available in client side. Simply, it is a Reverse Ajax library which makes it easy to call JavaScript functions from C#/VB.NET and to call C#/VB.NET functions from JavaScript. It has numerous features like event ordering, resource management, exception handling, marshaling, Ajax upload control, mono compatibility, WCF & .NET Remoting integration and scalable server push.

There are 2 ASP.NET MVC samples on the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Check out WebSync, a reverse AJAX/Comet server for .NET.

[www.frozenmountain.com/websync/](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/)

Comment: do i need to purchase websync

Comment: You can use the Community edition free of charge, if you need more than that, I'm afraid so.